# Are morph target animations possible in Threejs using a Blender object?

Tags: animation, three.js, blender

I'm attempting to animate a figurehead for use in a project that utilizes speech recognition and talks back to the user. The main library I was planning on using to display the figurehead is Three.js, which has two different methods for animation - animation clips and morph targets.

Multiple animation clips might be too cumbersome for the project, but morph targets seem to fit the criteria of being able to animate the face depending on certain sounds being present. I want to use Blender to set up the morph targets, but much of the literature I'm reviewing seems contradictory. The [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html) itself seems to suggest they are synonymous, but [this article](https://blenderartists.org/t/shape-keys-is-not-morph-target/390884) suggests that they are not the same (although they're trying to morph between two different object, so it may not be applicable).

Any insight from more experienced individuals on this course of action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Three.js, which has two different methods for animation - animation clips and morph targets.

I'm afraid this is not true. An instance of `THREE.AnimationClip` is nothing else than a reusable set of keyframe tracks which represent an animation.

You are referring to animation techniques. Skeletal animation as well as morph target animation are both supported in `three.js`.

If you author `Shape Keys` in Blender and export the asset to `glTF`, it's possible to import them as morph targets into `three.js` via `THREE.GLTFLoader`.

`three.js R113`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This helps very much.